# SQL query to check if a value isn't present

Tags: sql, oracle

First of all, I really don't know how to formulate my question.

I have different companies in a database.

I would like to know which companies doesn't have an "analyst" profile.

Here is my query:

```
select
t.name as "name"
t.pre as "first name"
t.id as "# account"
t.profile as "Profile"
b.cod_miss as "Mission"
b.df_missn as "End date"


from sr.v t 
inner join od.e_lds on t.niu_ld = b.niu_ld
where b.cod_miss = 'APPROV'
and t.profile = 'Analyst'
```

This query gives me all the analyst for every companies in my database.
But I would like to have all the companies that does NOT have any analyst.
how do I do it? I tried using 'and t.profile <> 'analyst' " but obviously this is not working well...

**EDIT**:

I tried the accepted answer, but i noticed it just returns me everyone that is NOT an analyst.

Let's say there is a company X with 3 employees. One of them is an analyst. I would not want that company to come up in my results. but if there is company Y with 2 employees, and none of them is an "analyst", then I would like this company to come up in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, that would be `not exists`. Something like this:

```
select *
from sr.v 
where not exists (select null 
                  from od.e_lds b
                  where b.niu_ld = t.niu_ld
                    and t.profile = 'Analyst'
                 );
```

---

Applied to your query:

```
select
  t.name as "name"
  t.pre as "first name"
  t.id as "# account"
  t.profile as "Profile"
  b.cod_miss as "Mission"
  b.df_missn as "End date"
from sr.v t inner join od.e_lds b on t.niu_ld = b.niu_ld
where b.cod_miss = 'APPROV'
  --
  and not exists (select null 
                  from od.e_lds c
                  where c.niu_ld = t.niu_ld
                    and t.profile = 'Analyst'
                 );
```

---

**[EDIT #2, with some sample data]**

This is an example that shows what you tried to explain in words (would be better if you posted sample data, though). As you can see, one of employees in BMW is Analyst while nobody in SAP is >> therefore, SAP is being returned.

```
SQL> with test (company, ename, profile) as
  2    (select 'BMW', 'Scott', 'Analyst' from dual union all
  3     select 'BMW', 'King' , 'Manager' from dual union all
  4     select 'BMW', 'Mike' , 'Clerk'   from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'SAP', 'John' , 'Clerk'   from dual union all
  7     select 'SAP', 'Fred' , 'Manager' from dual
  8    )
  9  select a.company, a.ename, a.profile
 10  from test a
 11  where not exists (select null
 12                    from test b
 13                    where b.company = a.company
 14                      and b.profile = 'Analyst');

COMPANY    ENAME PROFILE
---------- ----- -------
SAP        Fred  Manager
SAP        John  Clerk

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why did you removed the inner join?

Comment: For simplicity. You know how to use it; you didn't know how to do the *NOT EXISTS* part, which is the "key" here.

Comment: can i join the tables before the "where not exists" clause?

Comment: sorry to bother you but I'm not sure How to make it work. I have values that needs to be met and I dont know where to put them. Could you please edit your answer to fit exactly my original query with the "where not exists" clause? I'm so lost and i've been bugging around for the past hour...

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more code. If it still doesn't work, please - edit your own question and post sample data (a few rows that illustrate the problem) and desired output; I'll take a look, then.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I edited my question. Hope i'm clear enough.. english isn,t my first langage, im french ! =(

Comment: I read what you wrote and composed another example (see EDIT #2). It shows that the NOT EXISTS principle actually *works* (i.e. returns correct output). As I said: if you posted sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements), it would be simpler for us to assist).

Comment: In your second edit, it should only return "SAP" once and not twice. Is it possible? Thanks again..

Comment: Yes; you'd just `select distinct a.company from ...`, but that means that you don't actually want any *names* or *profiles*, right?

Comment: Right. Just the company...

Comment: Then DISTINCT it is.