# Not exists clause isn't working as expected

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to search every company (`niu_lds`) that does NOT have any Analyst (`cod_role_acces`) working for it.

**Example:** Let's say there is a company X with 3 employees. One of them is an analyst. I would not want that company to come up in my results. but if there is company Y with 2 employees, and none of them is an "analyst", then I would like this company to come up in the result.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name_pers as "First Name",
    a.last_pers as "Last Name",
    a.id as "# account",
    a.cod_role_acces as "Profile", 
    a.niu_lds as "Company", 
    b.cod_missn as "Mission", 
    
FROM sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util a inner join ods.c_od_missn_ld b on a.niu_lds = b.niu_lds

WHERE a.cod_eta_util in ('VER', 'APPR')
and a.id_cod_sr_alim = '2'
and b.cod_missn = 'PHA'

 and not exists (select null
                 from sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util c 
                 where c.niu_lds = a.niu_lds
                 and a.cod_role_acces = 'ANALYST'
                );
```

My problem is it's returning me "company" that HAVE "analyst(s)"! I want to see all the company (niu_lds) that has no 'ANALYST'(cod_role_access) attributed to said company.

I already asked the question, and someone helped me a lot but I'm still not getting the expected output.

my first question : [SQL query to check if a value isn't present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265731/sql-query-to-check-if-a-value-isnt-present/70265769?noredirect=1#comment124213222_70265769)

Thank you

Comment: You would need to demonstrate with some sample data and a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer from Romeo with changing the null to 1 might get you there.

If it doesn't and you want to see visually what's happening to compare, you could turn the not exists function into a left join so you can see where values are getting placed.

Using the test example from the previous post -

```
with test (company, ename, profile) as
      (select 'BMW', 'Scott', 'Analyst' union all
       select 'BMW', 'King' , 'Manager' union all
      select 'BMW', 'Mike' , 'Clerk'  union all
      select 'SAP', 'John' , 'Clerk' union all
      select 'SAP', 'Fred' , 'Manager' 
    )
  select a.company, a.ename, a.profile, b.analyst
  from test a
  left join (select 1 as analyst, company
        from test
        where profile = 'Analyst') b
        on b.company = a.company
```

The following is the return -

| COMPANY | ENAME | PROFILE | ANALYST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | Scott | Analyst | 1 |
| BMW | King | Manager | 1 |
| BMW | Mike | Clerk | 1 |
| SAP | John | Clerk | null |
| SAP | Fred | Manager | null |

You can see that all of BMW is getting marked for Analyst, from here, if you wanted to build off the left join rather than not exists but 'hide' the column marking Analyst, add 'where b.analyst is null' and remove b.analyst from the select statement -

```
with test (company, ename, profile) as
      (select 'BMW', 'Scott', 'Analyst' union all
       select 'BMW', 'King' , 'Manager' union all
      select 'BMW', 'Mike' , 'Clerk'  union all
      select 'SAP', 'John' , 'Clerk' union all
      select 'SAP', 'Fred' , 'Manager' 
    )
  select a.company, a.ename, a.profile
  from test a
  left join (select 1 as analyst, company
        from test
        where profile = 'Analyst') b
        on b.company = a.company
where b.analyst is null
```

This returns the expected table -

| COMPANY | ENAME | PROFILE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SAP | John | Clerk |
| SAP | Fred | Manager |

**Edited to add OP's equivalents:**

These should match up with the logic originally posted and your code -

With AnalystFlag present -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name_pers as "First Name",
    a.last_pers as "Last Name",
    a.id as "# account",
    a.cod_role_acces as "Profile", 
    a.niu_lds as "Company", 
    b.cod_missn as "Mission", 
    c.analyst as "AnalystFlag"
    
FROM sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util a 
  inner join ods.c_od_missn_ld b 
    on a.niu_lds = b.niu_lds
  left join (select distinct 1 as analyst, niu_lds
                 from sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util
                 where cod_role_acces = 'ANALYST') c
                 on a.niu_lds = c.niu_lds

WHERE a.cod_eta_util in ('VER', 'APPR')
and a.id_cod_sr_alim = '2'
and b.cod_missn = 'PHA'
;
```

With AnalystFlag removed -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name_pers as "First Name",
    a.last_pers as "Last Name",
    a.id as "# account",
    a.cod_role_acces as "Profile", 
    a.niu_lds as "Company", 
    b.cod_missn as "Mission", 
    
FROM sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util a 
  inner join ods.c_od_missn_ld b 
    on a.niu_lds = b.niu_lds
  left join (select distinct 1 as analyst, niu_lds
                 from sr.c_r_v_obt_cp_util
                 where cod_role_acces = 'ANALYST') c
                 on a.niu_lds = c.niu_lds

WHERE a.cod_eta_util in ('VER', 'APPR')
and a.id_cod_sr_alim = '2'
and b.cod_missn = 'PHA'
and c.analyst IS NULL
;
```

Comment: i cant seem to reproduct the example on my code. Is it possible to show me what you mean using the code I provided?

Comment: I added in edits that I believe would be equivalent in your code - if the first version has companies missing an analyst flag, it could be an issue with the strings, you could try substituting "where cod_role_acces = 'ANALYST'" for "where upper(cod_role_acces) LIKE '%ANALYST%'" which should reduce issues with whitespace and case sensitivity.

Comment: I tried your code and it's still not working.. it's giving me companies with analysts also... thank you so much for all the effort!

Comment: When you run it with the Analyst flag present, is there a difference in the way the cod_role_acces manifests in the ones that flag vs don't flag? Is it flagging any? Did you try to swap "where cod_role_acces = 'ANALYST'" for "where upper(cod_role_acces) LIKE '%ANALYST%'"?

Comment: the first one gives me "1" on every colomn, and the second one nothing. I get almost the same result. I can see "Analyst" everywhere on the output..

Comment: Oh my - that's my bad - I corrected the second query. I had "and c.analyst IS NOT NULL" and it should have been "and c.analyst IS NULL"

Comment: can you just explain to me the part of 'left join (select1 1...)' I would like to be able to explain it if someone asks me about it! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure your level of familiarity, this article should provide the basis for a left join - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm . The subquery creates a table that gives the value 1 (aliased as analyst) and the niu_lds any time cod_role_acces is 'ANALYST'. Any niu_lds that aren't in the list will get a value of null for c.analyst after the left join, which is why the where clause keeps only null values for c.analyst, since values of 1 have an analyst. The subquery could actually be written as SELECT DISTINCT, which is probably more appropriate, so I'll edit it slightly again.

Comment: even when using 'distinct', it still gives me duplicates on 'niu_lds'. Everything works. It doesnt give me any values that has 'analyst' but it gives me duplicates...